# How to get HMAC key in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, aes, sha1, hmac

I am using OpenSSL and I want to extract my HMAC key and AES key from the session, so that I can accelerate HMAC and AES encryption with GPU in application.

Where can I get the keys after `SSL_accept`?
Is the AES key stored in `SSLHandle->enc_write_ctx->cipher_data`?
Where is the HMAC key stored?

Comment: Normally you would try to accelerate SSL by creating an engine for OpenSSL, not by retrieving data from the session itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `SSL*` called `ssl`, then look at `ssl->session` for the master key and `ssl->s3` for the current hamc key.

`ssl.h` has a `struct ssl_session_st`, and that's the `ssl->session` above. The master key is stored in `struct ssl_session_st`.

```
struct ssl_session_st
{
  int ssl_version;   /* what ssl version session info is
                      * being kept in here? */

  /* only really used in SSLv2 */
  unsigned int key_arg_length;
  unsigned char key_arg[SSL_MAX_KEY_ARG_LENGTH];
  int master_key_length;
  unsigned char master_key[SSL_MAX_MASTER_KEY_LENGTH];
  ...
}
```

Some derivation goes on, and you can see it in, for example, `s3_clnt.c`. SSL2 uses two session keys - one in each direction (client to server; and server to client). The key is used for both privacy and integrity protection. SSLv3 and above uses 6 keys - three in each direction (client to server; and server to client). One key is used for privacy, the second is used for integrity, and the third is used as a nonce or iv.

To see what the HMAC key is, take a look at, for example, `n_ssl3_mac` in `s3_enc.c` around line 700. You will see something like:

```
int n_ssl3_mac(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *md, int send)
{
  SSL3_RECORD *rec;
  unsigned char *mac_sec,*seq;
  EVP_MD_CTX md_ctx;
  ...

  if (send)
  {
    rec= &(ssl->s3->wrec);
    mac_sec= &(ssl->s3->write_mac_secret[0]);
    seq= &(ssl->s3->write_sequence[0]);
    hash=ssl->write_hash;
  }
  else
  {
    rec= &(ssl->s3->rrec);
    mac_sec= &(ssl->s3->read_mac_secret[0]);
    seq= &(ssl->s3->read_sequence[0]);
    hash=ssl->read_hash;
  }
  ...
```

TLS also uses the `ssl->s3` member. For example, from `t1_enc.c` around line 445:

```
mac_secret= &(s->s3->write_mac_secret[0]);
mac_secret_size = &(s->s3->write_mac_secret_size);
```

You might also be able to get a good look at the data in the `SSL*` object with `SSL_SESSION_print` using a `BIO` or `SSL_SESSION_print_fp`.